# Does pdb.set_trace() always overwrite an error traceback?

Tags: python, pdb

I've got a loop processing sockets, and I've set a pdb.set_trace() breakpoint to stop and inspect the results of the call to select.select() every time through the loop.  However, there are also bugs elsewhere in my code, and it seems that the standard traceback is being overwritten by pdb.set_trace.  As a result, when the program quits, the traceback points to the line immediately following the set_trace(), not the line that contained the error.

Is there a way to access the actual traceback, or does pdb.set_trace() clobber it?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
while True:
    read_socks, write_socks, _ = select.select(all_sockets, all_sockets, '')
    pdb.set_trace()

    if listen_socket.fileno() in read_socks:
        new_socket, address = listen_socket.accept()
        id_num = new_socket.fileno()
        all_sockets[id_num] = new_socket

    for id_num in write_socks:
        # do something that triggers an Assertion error
```

and then I get the traceback as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socktactoe_server.py", line 62, in <module>
    if listen_sock.fileno() in read_socks:
AssertionError
```

Here is a short reproducible test case; run it, hit `c` every time there is a breakpoint, after the second continue the `assert` raises an exception and it's reported for the wrong line:

```
import pdb
x = 0
while True:
    pdb.set_trace()
    y = "line of code not triggering an error"
    x += 1
    assert x != 3
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal_pdb_traceback.py", line 7, in <module>
    y = "line of code not triggering an error"
AssertionError
```

Comment: `set_trace()` does no such thing; you should have hit the debug prompt by that point instead of getting an `AssertionError`. Are you certain this is the code you run?

Comment: yes, I hit the debug prompt as I expected, every pass through the loop.  I'm using 'c' in pdb to continue executing the code.  On a later pass, I get the assertion error.

Comment: Note that the traceback uses the *current, on-disk* copy of the source code to find the line. If you changed the source code after you started the program, the wrong line could be shown. That's because the compiled bytecode only stores a line number and a filename, so if the file later changes, the indices into the file are incorrect.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know that.  However, that's not the case here.

Comment: I'm a hefty `pdb` user myself, and certainly never have seen the behaviour you describe, so I would still search for explanations in that direction.

Comment: You can see this behavior isolated here: https://gist.github.com/4079971

Comment: that gist works fine for me in Python 2.6 and 3.1, but indeed shows a problem in Python 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3. Looks like you found a bug!

Comment: Ah, cool, I'll submit it.  I am indeed running 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug in the Python `pdb` module! I can reproduce your simple case in Python versions 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3, while the problem is *not* present in Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6  or 3.1.

At first glance, I don't see a preexisting bug in the [python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/). Please report your problem there, with your minimal test case, as well as what python versions it can be reproduced on.